# Grails Blurb Plugin - Unable to resolve class Blurb

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I'm working through the book *Grails: A Quick-Start Guide* and have come upon a problem.  The book has me install the Blurb plugin, which seems to work, but states that we will be using it as if it were a domain class and using it a pre-existing controller.  The code that I am to add to the controller looks like this

```
def blurb = Blurb.findByName("custom_${event.id}" )
if (!blurb){
    blurb = new Blurb(name:"custom_${event.id}" , content:"" ).save()
}
```

When I do this I receive the same error in the IDE and the run output

'**unable to resolve class Blurb**' and I am directed specifically to this line `blurb = new Blurb(name:"custom_${event.id}" , content:"" ).save()`

Can anyone tell me what might be going wrong?  I'm assuming the plugin is installed properly because if I try to access it's controller/action directly '*http://localhost:8080/TekDays/blurb/create*' the plugin's provided view renders properly.

Thanks!

--
For reference I am using STS / Grails 1.3.7

---

**Update 2011.05.12 7:45AM CST**

I've attached a screenshot showing my project from the STS interface to show how my project is laid out in the event that it is package related as Burt indicated.  The issue though is I'm not sure how do to the import statement so perhaps that screenshot will help.

Here is the current code in the Dashboard Controller.

```
package tekdays

class DashboardController {
...
}
```

I've tried adding the following lines per Burt's suggestion, but I obviously don't have it right

```
package tekdays
package my.package  <--unexpected token: package

class DashboardController {
```

I tried changing out my with tekdays and default and both yield the same result.

Am I doing that wrong?

Thanks!

[image: Grails ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Blurb class is in the default package, so if your controller is in a package you'll need to use a Groovy trick to access it:

```
package my.package

import Blurb as Blurb

class MyController {

   def action = {
      def blurb = Blurb.findByName("custom_${event.id}" )
      if (!blurb) {
         blurb = new Blurb(name:"custom_${event.id}" , content:"" ).save()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Burt Thanks for the help, but I must have something wrong in my execution of your advice.  I've updated my original question with the results of my changes and a screenshot of my Grails project in STS. - Thanks

Comment: Remove "package my.package". You didn't show your full controller code so I was assuming it's in a package, and that was a dummy name. The only change you'll need is to add the line "import Blurb as Blurb" after the line "package tekdays" to get around the limitation that you can't (ordinarily) access default-package classes from classes in packages.

Comment: @Burt okay I have removed that as you suggested.  Now it's package tekdays, your import statement, and then my class declaration.  When I do that the import statement gives the error 'unable to resolve class Blurb'

Comment: Right-click on the project node in the left tree, and run Grails Tools | Refresh Dependencies. If you installed the plugin from the commandline, STS might not be aware of it. If that doesn't fix it, also run Project | Clean to force a full recompile.

Comment: @Burt I performed the steps you indicated and unfortunately the error persists on the import statement.  I've installed/uninstalled the plugin so many times I'm not sure if the current install is via the command line of the plugin manager.

Comment: I guess you'll need to move the Blurb class into a package. I was testing prototype code but now that I use the actual plugin it's failing for me, and it appears to be due to the way Grails compiles plugin code separately from application code. Create a 'tekdays' directory in the plugin's grails-app/domain folder and move Blurb.groovy there, and add a "package tekdays" line at the top. Remove the "import Blurb as Blurb" line from your controller since they'll now be in the same package. You might want to contact the author and suggest that he do the same - classes should always be in packages.

Comment: @Burt That seems to have solved the issue - thanks so much for your help!